# Symfony 3.4 - Webpack Encore and DOMPurify

Tags: javascript, symfony, webpack-encore, dompurify

I'm trying to integrate DOMPurify into my Symfony project, but I keep getting

> DOMPurify isn't defined

In my browser's console.  In my `app.js` I have:

```
import '../scss/custom.scss';
import $ from 'jquery';
import DOMPurify from 'dompurify';

global.$ = global.jQuery = $;

window.Popper = require('popper.js');
require('bootstrap');
```

And in my template:

```
{% block js %}
    {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}
{% endblock %}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('form[name=search_full]').submit(function(event) {
        let search = $('input[name=search]');
        search.value = DOMPurify.sanitize(search.value);
    });
</script>
```

I'm not sure how to correctly integrate it into my project.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else having a similar issue, the solution appears to be adding the following line to your `app.js` file:

```
window.DOMPurify = require('dompurify');
```